# iOS UISplitViewController - How to restore navigation state when changing from compact to regular layout

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, ios14

I am implementing the new UISplitViewController APIs introduced in iOS 14. When the app is in regular mode, I have a .doubleColumn layout with a primary view being an UICollectionView for navigation and corresponding UIViewControllers for the secondary view.
For the .compact layout I am using an UITabBarController.

Now I want to implement the navigation state restoration when the layout changes from regular to compact and vice versa. I already watched the corresponding WWDC 2020 Video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10105/ where they talk about how a state restoration implementation could look like. What is missing there is what actual methods are used to detect the layout changes.

What I already found out is that I can use the `splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, topColumnForCollapsingToProposedTopColumn proposedTopColumn: UISplitViewController.Column)` method to detect when the SplitVC changes to the `.compact` mode.

And the `splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, displayModeForExpandingToProposedDisplayMode proposedDisplayMode: UISplitViewController.DisplayMode)` method when the SplitVC is going from .compact to .regular.

Now to my question. When I want to change the secondary view controller for the SplitVC, in the latter delegate method, in order to select the correct ViewController, that matches the currently visible one in the TabBar (.compact mode), my app is crashing with the following error message.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Mutating UISplitViewController with -setViewController:forColumn: is not allowed during a delegate callback.'
```

How I am supposed to prepare the SplitVC when changing back to the .regular mode when I cannot use `setViewController(_ vc: UIViewController?, for column: UISplitViewController.Column)` inside the delegate methods ?

I couldn't find any official code samples or documentations about that. I appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Not sure but you can try to change splitViewController's view controller in -`(void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator`.
Check for compact / regular size class and make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I use UISplitViewControllerDelegate's delegate method splitViewControllerDidExpand(_ svc: UISplitViewController). In this method you can obtain your tab bar's selectedIndex (the VC that was active in compact mode) which allows you to determine which VC to show in regular mode. Finally, use showDetailViewController(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?) to show the appropriate VC

There may be other ways but the above is working fine for me.